# Cobol Reference Modification: What exactly does "MOVE Variable(Variable +literal:literal) TO Variable" do?

Tags: cobol

There is one thing which I don't understand about reference modification in Cobol.

The example goes like this:

```
MOVE VARIABLE(VARIABLE2 +4:2) TO VARIABLE3
```

Now I do not qutie understand what the "+4:2" references to. Does it mean that the first two signs 4 signs after the target are moved? Meaning if for example VARIABLE (the 1st) is filled with "123456789" and VARIABLE2 contains the 2nd and 3rd position within that variable (so"23"), the target is "23 +4" meaning "789". Then the first two positions in the target (indicated by the ":2") are moved to VARIABLE3. So in the end VARIABLE3 would contain "78".

Am I understanding this right or am I making a false assumption about that instruction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(VARIABLE2 +4:2)` is a syntax error, because the starting position must be an arithmetic expression. There must be a space after the `+` for this `reference modification` to be valid. And, `VARIABLE2` must be numeric and the expression shall evaluate to an integer.

Once corrected, then `4` is added to the content of `VARIABLE2`. That is the left-most (or starting position) within `VARIABLE1` for the move. `2` characters are moved to `VARIABLE3`. If `VARIABLE3` is longer than two characters, the remaining positions are filled with spaces.

---

From the 2002 COBOL standard:

> 8.7.1 Arithmetic operators
>
> There are five binary **arithmetic operators** and two unary arithmetic operators that may be used in arithmetic expressions. They are represented by specific COBOL characters that **shall be preceded by a space and followed by a space** except that no space is required between a left parenthesis and a unary operator or between a unary operator and a left parenthesis.

Emphasis added.

Comment: Coding like that should be avoided - it confuses people as you have just shown. Ideally it should be coded as: ADD 4 TO VARIABLE2. MOVE VARIABLE1(VARIABLE2:2) TO VARIABLE3.

Comment: As per OP's code, the output in VARIABLE3 will be zero. For example, if VARIABLE2 contains '01', then the output would be '56'

Comment: @SrinivasanJv - It will be a syntax error, because it was not an arithmetic expression. I edited the answer to add that requirement.

Comment: Hi @Rick Smith. I agree that it would be a syntax error. I meant the output to be 0 after fixing the syntax error.

Comment: @SrinivasanJv - Ah! However, the OP used `"23"` suggesting that `VARIABLE2` is alphanumeric.

Comment: Yes! if OP has declared VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2 data items as alphanumeric, the program would issue error, as alphanumeric data items are being used in an arithmetic expression.

Comment: @SrinivasanJv - I originally wrote "`VARIABLE2` must be an integer", which implied that `VARIABLE2` must be numeric. I have clarified, in the first paragraph, that "syntax error" included both problems.